# Desktop nav version background-color doesn't work?

Tags: css

So something is overriding the background-color property in my webpage. It works just fine in the mobile-scaled version, but for some reason when it runs the media-query the background color matches the body background color.

It does work, however, when I use nav{position: fixed;} but I can't set it as fixed because there's a header above it, so when you scroll down the nav sticks and there's a space above it.

So what's causing the media-query background color to be overridden?

*EDIT*

This is what I'm seeing when I have it fullscreen on my computer
[desktop nav shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iAKE.png)
And this is what I'm seeing when mobile layout [mobile nav shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHQ3S.png)

(Sorry if it's an obvious answer and I'm just not seeing it)

```css
/*NAV*/

nav 
{
 background-color: #3f3f3f; /*this color doesn't work in the media query*/
 width: 100%;
 color: #e9e9e9;
 z-index: 3; 
}

/*MOBILE FIRST FORMATTING*/

nav ul 
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav li a 
{
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover,
nav .hambut:hover 
{
  background-color: #189000; /*green*/
}


/*NAV LINKS*/

nav .menu 
{
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/*MENU FORMATTING*/

nav .hamicon 
{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 2em 1.5em;
  position: relative;
}

nav .hamicon .navicon 
{
  background: #e9e9e9;
  display: block;
  height: .15em;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 1.5em;
}

nav .hamicon .navicon:before,
nav .hamicon .navicon:after 
{
  background: #e9e9e9;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

nav .hamicon .navicon:before 
{
  top: .375em;
}

nav .hamicon .navicon:after 
{
  top: -.375em;
}

/*HAMBURGER BUTTON*/

nav .hambut 
{
  display: none;
}

nav .hambut:checked ~ .menu 
{
  max-height: 15em;
}

nav .hambut:checked ~ .hamicon .navicon 
{
  background: transparent;
}

nav .hambut:checked ~ .hamicon .navicon:before 
{
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

nav .hambut:checked ~ .hamicon .navicon:after 
{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

nav .hambut:checked ~ .hamicon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
nav .hambut:checked ~ .hamicon:not(.steps) .navicon:after 
{
  top: 0;
}


/*DESKTOP NAV FORMATTING*/


@media (min-width: 48em) 
{
 
 nav
 {
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
 }
 nav li 
 {
  float: left;
 }

 nav li a 
 {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
 }

 nav .menu 
 {
  clear: none;
  float: right;
  max-height: none;
 }

 nav .hamicon
 {
  display: none;
 }
  
}
```

```html
  <nav> 
           
   <input class="hambut" type="checkbox" id="hambut" />
   <label class="hamicon" for="hambut"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
   
   <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#trailer">Trailer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#download">Download</a></li>
    <li><a href="#devs">Devs</a></li>
   </ul>


       </nav>
```

Comment: seems to work fine for me

Answer (score 0):

This happens because in the desktop version you are using `float: right` to align your `<ul>` element. [`float` property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) has a weird behavior and it's not been designed to align block element, it's been designed to align inline elements instead.

For this reason, when an element has an automatic height and its child use `float`, the parent will ignore the size of that element to compute the height.

In your case the consequence is that, in your desktop version, your `<nav>` element won't use the height of `<ul>` to compute its own height, since there's no an explicit height and there are no other children, the resultant computed height will so be **0px**.

You have two solutions, the first is to set a fixed height:

```
nav {
  ..
  height: 50px;
}
```

The second, which is advised, is to use a so called [**clearfix**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp).

A clearfix will cancel the effects of `float` and the parent element will use again all its children sizes to compute the height.

```css
/*NAV*/

nav 
{
 background-color: #3f3f3f; /*this color doesn't work in the media query*/
 width: 100%;
 color: #e9e9e9;
 z-index: 3; 
}

/*MOBILE FIRST FORMATTING*/

nav ul 
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav li a 
{
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover,
nav .hambut:hover 
{
  background-color: #189000; /*green*/
}


/*NAV LINKS*/

nav .menu 
{
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/*MENU FORMATTING*/

nav .hamicon 
{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 2em 1.5em;
  position: relative;
}

nav .hamicon .navicon 
{
  background: #e9e9e9;
  display: block;
  height: .15em;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 1.5em;
}

nav .hamicon .navicon:before,
nav .hamicon .navicon:after 
{
  background: #e9e9e9;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

nav .hamicon .navicon:before 
{
  top: .375em;
}

nav .hamicon .navicon:after 
{
  top: -.375em;
}

/*HAMBURGER BUTTON*/

nav .hambut 
{
  display: none;
}

nav .hambut:checked ~ .menu 
{
  max-height: 15em;
}

nav .hambut:checked ~ .hamicon .navicon 
{
  background: transparent;
}

nav .hambut:checked ~ .hamicon .navicon:before 
{
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

nav .hambut:checked ~ .hamicon .navicon:after 
{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

nav .hambut:checked ~ .hamicon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
nav .hambut:checked ~ .hamicon:not(.steps) .navicon:after 
{
  top: 0;
}


/*DESKTOP NAV FORMATTING*/


@media (min-width: 48em) 
{
 
 nav
 {
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
 }
 nav li 
 {
  float: left;
 }

 nav li a 
 {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
 }

 nav .menu 
 {
  clear: none;
  float: right;
  max-height: none;
 }

 nav .hamicon
 {
  display: none;
 }
  
}
```

```html
  <nav> 
           
   <input class="hambut" type="checkbox" id="hambut" />
   <label class="hamicon" for="hambut"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
   
   <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#trailer">Trailer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#download">Download</a></li>
    <li><a href="#devs">Devs</a></li>
   </ul>
            <!-- This is the clearfix -->
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
            <!-- End of clearfix -->
       </nav>
```